# Label in custom cell is null when populating UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitableview, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin.iOS to build an iOS app. I'm using a storyboard and have created a `UITableViewController` with a grouped table using custom cells. The cell contains a label to which I want to assign a value.

Overriding the getcell method in the datasource to set the text property of the label throws a null exception and I can't find why? I've checked the outlet and it's there. Any tips on how to find the error?

```
public partial class NameListScreen : UITableViewController
{
    MyTableSource _source = null;

    public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

        LoadNameList();          
    }

    void LoadNameList ()
    {
        var service = new MyService();
        var names = service.GetAllNames();

        _source = new MyTableSource(names);

        this.TableView.Source = _source;
    }
}

public class MyTableSource : UITableViewSource {

    protected List<string> _names;
    protected string _cellIdentifier = "MyCell";

    public MyTableSource (List<string> items)
    {
        _names = items;
    }

    public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
    { 
        return _names.Count;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // Request a recycled cell to save memory
        var cell = (MyTableCell) tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_cellIdentifier);

        // If there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        cell = new MyTableCell();

        cell.UpdateCell(indexPath, _names[indexPath.Item]);

        return cell;
    }
}


public partial class MyTableCell : UITableViewCell
{

    public MyTableCell () : base ()
    { }

    public MyTableCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    { }

    public void UpdateCell(NSIndexPath indexPath, string name)
    {
        this._indexPath = indexPath;
        this._id = track.TrackId;
        this.NameLabel.Text = name;   //This row throws exception as NameLabel is null, why? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: Just the usual "object ref not set to an instance of..." as the NameLabel object is null. The question was why it's null since the view is about to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I think you did not load the xib in the correct manner. Inside you custom cell just put a static method like the following.

```
// Inside MyTableCell
public static MyTableCell Create()
{
    NSArray topLevelObjects = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("MyTableCell", null, null);
    MyTableCell cell = Runtime.GetNSObject(topLevelObjects.ValueAt(0)) as MyTableCell;
    return cell;
}
```

This pattern is now used in new Xamarin cell creation template. The only difference is that `UINib` class is used (I can't verify it since I don't have Xamarin Studio with me).

Then, in `GetCell` method you should do like the following

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    // Request a recycled cell to save memory
    var cell = (MyTableCell) tableView.DequeueReusableCell(_cellIdentifier);

    // If there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
    if (cell == null)
        cell = MyTableCell.Create();

    cell.UpdateCell(indexPath, _names[indexPath.Item]);
    return cell;
}
```

You need to `[Register("MyTableCell")]` in `.cs` for using in XIB if you haven't registered it yet. You also need to set the type of the designed cell as `MyTableCell` in your XIB file.

But, play a bit with Xamarin template (you can choose them if you create a new iOS file) and you will find a custom cell template.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but I get an exception when executing the LoadNib("MyTableCell"): 

    MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/.../MyIosApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyTableCell'..."

As the table cell is created using storyboards the class is divided in two partial classes where the MyTableCell.designer.cs has the register statement. I'm guessing that's enough?